# String evaluation with quotes

Tags: python

I would like to evaluate a string that contains double quotes, for example as a function parameter or in an assignment:

```
argument = "string with \"quotes\""  # any value, e.g., read from file.
value = eval("\"" + argument + "\"")
```

fails:

```
    string with "quotes"
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know I could use `value = eval("\'" + argument + "\'")` instead, but now this is going to fail when `argument = "string with 'quotes'"`.

And I would like something robust that works with any string `argument` (e.g., read in a file) with the objective to actually use it as a function (string) parameter, maybe like that: `eval("f(" + "\"" + argument + "\"" + ")")`.

Comment: What are you expecting `value` to be?  Seems like it would be identical to `argument`, so what is the point?

Comment: Yes, I would like ```value``` to be equal to ```argument``` in this example, in order to simplify the question. But see the other example with a call to a function ```f``` where ```argument``` is a parameter. The question is valid for even more complex expression to evaluate.

Comment: Perhaps your question is too contrived, but is there a reason not to use, say, [format strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#arbitrary-expressions)?

Comment: How format strings would help here?

Comment: What is keeping `f(argument)` from working?  We have no idea what that function is supposed to do.

Comment: @jasonharper I see. I omitted the ```eval``` around ```f```. Next, you will ask why ```eval``` around ```f```, and this is because I make  loop over many functions and ```f``` will actually be replaced by a variable. I did not put the entire example in order to focus on the problem of quotes. I really need to call ```eval``` or use ```ast``` .

Comment: If the name of `f()` is given by a string, then `eval("f")(argument)` does the job without any concerns about quoting the parameters.  Or perhaps `globals()["f"](argument)`, if you know the string is simply the name of a globally-defined function, and not a possibly more complicated expression.

Comment: Also, a "loop over many functions" would be much easier if you looped over the actual functions, rather than their names as strings: `funcs = [f1, f2, f3]` / `for f in funcs: f(argument)`

Comment: @jasonharper Indeed this is a good approach to avoid my issue. Thanks for this idea!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is your intended result, but maybe something like this?

```
backslash="\\"
argument = "some " + backslash + "\"data" + backslash + "\" quoted data"
value = eval("\"" + argument + "\"")
print(value)
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, which for a general string would be written as
```eval("\"" + argument.replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"")```
This is not pretty, and does not seem very robust, though.